# Disoriented when writing JavaScript - Architectural Integration - Grockage

Tags: javascript

I'm a reasonably experience programmer (10+ years), and have only hacked JavaScript.  I don't feel comfortable writing more than a few lines of it, but I'm seeing it more and more unavoidable to learn properly.

I get the same feeling writing JavaScript as I first did writing Unix shell scripts.  I didn't fully understand the environment, where things are going, and so forth.  It took a few well-timed suggestions to sort it all out.

I have a hard time with Js tools.  I'm okay with almost any text editor, but is there anything other than alert('foo') and Firefox error console to see what the heck is going on?

Ps. I have bought books.  Yes, I can write code snippits, but nothing sufficiently explained the whole paradigm. It's all code snippits, with no larger picture of how to integrate it architecturally with server side scripts, and not have to duplicate everything on the server side.

Maybe that's the answer. . write some on the server side?

edit:

tl;dr AMA OO PHP programmer. how do I quickly and completely grok javascript/jquery?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, can you rephrase it a little? What languages are you used to programming in?

Comment: "but is there anything other than alert('foo') and Firefox error console to see what the heck is going on" - have you heard of Firebug [ http://getfirebug.com/ ]? It's a pretty amazing tool both for web development in general and for JS. It allows step-through debugging of Javascript amongst other things like helpful javascript errors. It may help you to avoid the dreaded alert() mess that often builds up when debugging JS.

Comment: Client-side JavaScript is typically not at all “integrated” architecturally into the server-side, even if the server-side scripts are written in JavaScript (which is rare). For most applications, you should consider the browser scripts (where available; don't forget webapps should continue to work with no JS present at all) and server scripts to be loosely-coupled applications communicating via HTTP.

Comment: Here's a case in point:  I have written a complete Forms package abstracted like Zend's.  It can populate form element errors/results, redirect then display them.  I now have it passing back a JSON array if it's called by Ajax, (so it will work either way), but trying to get it to do the same thing (present errors/results) back into the DOM is a brain cluster minefield for me.  Why is this so hard in the browser?  I guess I don't fully understand the DOM.  You have to find everything. Elements are not somehow just addressable by id.  Why?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: by integrated I mean designed intelligently, as though the developer knew what they doing.

Answer (score 1):

This article might be helpful to you: [Organizing A jQuery Application](http://jupiterjs.com/news/organizing-a-jquery-application). It dissects a non-trivial jQuery application and explains how to architect a whole JavaScript application (as opposed to code snippets). You can download the code there, and sing along.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use the console tab of Firebug, including breakpoints.  It's a simple and powerful way to see what's actually going on in your scripts.

Firebug also gives you a JS command line to work with, which is a great way to experiment with short snippets and see what they do.

http://getfirebug.com/javascript